# Data communication between 2 ObservableObjects

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observableobject, data-communication

I have 2 independent `ObservableObject`s called `ViewModel1` and `ViewModel2`.

`ViewModel2` has an array of strings:

`@Published var strings: [String] = []`.

Whenever that array is modified i want `ViewModel1` to be informed.

What's the recommended approach to achieve this?

Comment: `ViewModel1` could subscribe to changes in `strings`, e.g. `viewModel2.$strings.sink{...}`

Comment: There might be many, could you be more specific about your context?

Comment: @Asperi not sure how more specific I can be without going too much into detail. Like I wrote they are two independent classes handling with very different responsibilities. But I need the first class to be notified whenever something in the second class changes.

Comment: If you want to keep them independent then use NotificationCenter

Comment: @Asperi i don't think NotificationCenter is a good fit because it's only ViewModel1 that's interested in the changes. What I meant with independent is that the classes have different responsibilities.

Comment: Are both view models being created by a common parent? Or are they being created in totally separate parts of the code?

Comment: @jnpdx for simplicity both can be created by a common parent. However it would be interesting to see the proposed solution if they're created in separate parts of code.

Comment: You would be better off using the built-in features of the View data struct, e.g. dependency tracking and change observing, rather than re-implement it all yourself in objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, there are a number of potential solutions to this, like the aforementioned `NotificationCenter` and singleton ideas.

To me, this seems like a scenario where Combine would be rather useful:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel1 : ObservableObject {
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func connect(_ publisher: AnyPublisher<[String],Never>) {
        cancellable = publisher.sink(receiveValue: { (newStrings) in
            print(newStrings)
        })
    }
}

class ViewModel2 : ObservableObject {
    @Published var strings: [String] = []
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm1 = ViewModel1()
    @ObservedObject private var vm2 = ViewModel2()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("add item") {
                vm2.strings.append("\(UUID().uuidString)")
            }
            
            ChildView(connect: vm1.connect)
            
        }.onAppear {
            vm1.connect(vm2.$strings.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView : View {
    var connect : (AnyPublisher<[String],Never>) -> Void
    @ObservedObject private var vm2 = ViewModel2()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Connect child publisher") {
            connect(vm2.$strings.eraseToAnyPublisher())
            vm2.strings = ["Other strings","From child view"]
        }
    }
}
```

To test this, first try pressing the "add item" button -- you'll see in the console that `ViewModel1` receives the new values.

Then, try the `Connect child publisher` button -- now, the initial connection is cancelled and a new one is made to the child's iteration of `ViewModel2`.

In order for this scenario to work, you always have to have a reference to `ViewModel1` and `ViewModel2`, or at the least, the `connect` method, as I demonstrated in `ChildView`. You could easily pass this via dependency injection or even through an `EnvironmentObject`

`ViewModel1` could also be changed to instead of having 1 connection, having many by making `cancellable` a `Set<AnyCancellable>` and adding a connection each time if you needed a one->many scenario.

Using `AnyPublisher` decouples the idea of having a specific types for either side of the equation, so it would be just as easy to connect `ViewModel4` to `ViewModel1`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This is really neat, I was looking for a reasonable modern method to connect two `@StateObject` objects to pass particular pieces of state around, and this is really that. One neat thing I found is that `@Published` acts as `CurrentValueSubject`, so when you create the connection, you also get the initial state (which is what I needed), as well as any future changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I found this method working well, just using the idea of reference type and taking advantage of class like using shared one!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel2: ViewModel2 = ViewModel2.shared
    @State var index: Int = Int()
    
    var body: some View {

        Button("update strings array of ViewModel2") {

            viewModel2.strings.append("Hello" + index.description)
            index += 1
        }

        
    }
}


class ViewModel1: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: ViewModel1 = ViewModel1()
    
    @Published var onReceiveViewModel2: Bool = Bool() {
        
        didSet {
        
            print("strings array of ViewModel2 got an update!")
            print("new update is:", ViewModel2.shared.strings)

        }
        
    }
    
}


class ViewModel2: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: ViewModel2 = ViewModel2()
    
    @Published var strings: [String] = [String]() {
        
        didSet { ViewModel1.shared.onReceiveViewModel2.toggle() }
        
    }
    
}
```